# Custom constraint validator not working when annotated bean used as a collection inside another bean

Tags: java, spring, validation

I am creating rest service using Spring boot and to validate my DTOs, I am using java validation api.

In some DTOs, I have to do cross field validation so I am using Custom validators.

Here in my DTO, I have to check if both **weight** and **weight_unit** are present or both are absent. If only one of them is present then I must throw validation error.

It works perfectly if I use this DTO in another DTO directly but fails when I use it as Collection of DTO. It throws **org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException**.

Custom Validator

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { ProductWeightValidatorImpl.class })
public @interface ProductWeightValidator {

    String message() default "{com.inventory.validator.ProductWeightValidator.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Custom Validator Implementation

```
public class ProductWeightValidatorImpl implements ConstraintValidator<ProductWeightValidator, ProductDTO> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ProductWeightValidator constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(ProductDTO product, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return Objects.nonNull(product.getWeight()) && StringUtil.nullOrEmpty(product.getWeightUnit()) || Objects.isNull(product.getWeight()) && StringUtil.nonNullNonEmpty(product.getWeightUnit());
    }
}
```

Bean on which validator is applied

```
@ProductWeightValidator(message = "weight and weight_unit must be provided together")
public class ProductDTO extends BaseDTO {

    // other fields

    private Double weight;

    @JsonProperty("weight_unit")
    private String weightUnit;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Other bean where this bean is used as collection

```
public class ProductListDTO extends BaseDTO {

    @Valid
    private List<ProductDTO> products = new ArrayList<>(0);

    //getters and setters

}
```

Now when I pass only weight or weight_unit in request, it throws exception **Invalid property 'products[]' of bean class [com.inventory.DTO.ProductListDTO]: Invalid index in property path 'products[]'**

Comment: What if you use Array rather than List in the ProductListDTO ?

Comment: well it worked with array, but is that the only way?

Comment: See also https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26500410/InvalidPropertyException-on-trying-to-bind-with-ArrayList-in-a-form-in-Spring-MVC.html

Comment: Include where you construct ProductListDTO objects

Comment: I don't construct it, it is used in controller & comes as request body

Comment: I have used similar code in rest controller but validation is not being fired for method , I have updated Element type to method

Comment: Initially, my validation was not invoked when I just used `@Valid` along with `@RequestBody`. Later, I found that we should use `@Validated` on our restController in order to make it work for collection validation. I hope this helps. For basic understanding on steps for validating DTO, have a look at [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pkaYjJVlyk) this video.